# handlebars.js #each array. Use first item as a headline?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have the following data:

```
var test = [];
test.push({typ: 'a', name="bur"});
test.push({typ: 'a', name="fur"});
test.push({typ: 'b', name="kok"});
test.push({typ: 'b', name="bur"});
```

Im rendering that with handlebars.js, and use it in this template:

```
{{#each .}}
  <div>
  <div>{{ name }}</div>
  </div> 
{{/each}}
```

That works fine, but i want to put "typ" as a headline on it like this:

```
<div class="head">a</div>
<div class="name">bur</div>
<div class="name">fur</div>
<div class="head">b</div>
<div class="name">kok</div>
<div class="name">bur</div>
```

But how do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not transform your object and do it this way:

JS:

```
var postProcessed = {};

test.forEach(function(val){ //Look for support of forEach you can just use for loop for older browser support if you are running this on the browser (Node should be fine).
    postProcessed[val.typ] = postProcessed[val.typ] || [];
    postProcessed[val.typ].push(val.name);
});
//{"a":["bur","fur"],"b":["kok","bur"]}
```

Template:

```
{{#each .}}
     <div class="head">{{ @key }}</div>
     {{#each .}}
          <div class="name">{{ this }}</div>
     {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DzdA5/)**

You cannot do too many things in Handlebars (though you have handlebar helpers and add your own helper). I would suggest you to try to make your modal and template adjusted and mostly in a one-one fashion.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but I think it'd be cleaner to setup your CSS this way:

```
div {
  /* Header style */
}

div ~ div {
  /* normal style */
}
```

The Handlebars solution would be to use the special value `{{@index}}` (or `@key` for objects) inside the loop to access the index and set style accordingly. (But this is a lot of overhead because Handlebars is logic less, so you'd probably need to create a helper `ifEqual0` or something like that...)

The cleaner way when using Handlebars would be to separate your array as `header` and `items` and passing that as argument to the template.